# Alternative to pull events from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Looking for alternatives on how to use the events API since the Facebook changes.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes/

Our app currently uses /search endpoint, pulling events based on a /location (miles radius). Is this totally revoked or is there a way to work around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer use the /search endpoint with the following object types: event, group, page, user

Please read: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4

Currently to access events you can use a user endpoint such as ‘/me/events’ or ‘/me/events/not-replied’ using an access token valid for that user. you can get the events that the user was invited to or is going/interested

You can access an event endpoint /{event-id} with an user access token if that user has been invited or is going/attending or is the creator of that event.

I believe its possible (but didn’t test it yet) to access to a specific page events endpoint, such as /{page_id}/events with a page access_token such as manage_pages, if Facebook already approved that permission and the page owner accepted the permission.